# Batch script to copy two different file extension (.doc and .log) to newly created folder or directory (with date)

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I'm new to scripting and I'm writing a batch file that will copy the recent or newly created files (.doc and .log) from two different source/directory and create a destination folder name "backup(date today)"
Basically , the two files are from different source and copy to one folder

New_doc.doc from C:\Doc_backup
New_log.log from C:\Log_backup
Destination: d:\file_backup\backup20140330

My code below will create a folder (with date) and copy the only file from source. 
but I don't know copying two different file from different source to single folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal
::Create Directory with date
SET dd=%date:~0,2%
SET mm=%date:~3,2%
SET yy=%date:~6,4%
SET date=%yy%%mm%%dd%
md c:\file_backup\backup%date%

set srcDir=c:\doc_backup
set srcDir2=c:\log_backup
set destdir=c:\file_backup\backup%date%
set lastmod=
pushd %srcDir%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.DOC /b /od 2^>NUL') do set lastmod=%%a
if "%lastmod%"=="" echo Could not locate files.&goto :eof
copy "%lastmod%" "%destDir%"
pause
```

Comment: what formats do .doc and .log have? are they plain text files? have you tried `copy 1.doc+1.log 1.txt` ?

Comment: yes, a normal plain text file a  .doc. filename are changing everyday wiith date and time.

Answer (score 0):

All `copy` task could be performed, supposing variables `srcDir`  and `destDir` are defined correctly, with next code snippet without `for` loop:

```
pushd "%destDir%"
copy /B "%srcDir%\*.doc"
popd
```

However, let's correct some mistakes in your code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
::Create Directory with date
SET "dd=%date:~0,2%"
SET "mm=%date:~3,2%"
SET "yy=%date:~6,4%"
SET "xdate=%yy%%mm%%dd%"
md "c:\file_backup\backup%xdate%"

set "srcDir=c:\doc_backup"
set "destdir=c:\log_backup\backup%xdate%"
md "%destdir%" 2>NUL
rem set lastmod=
pushd %srcDir%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.DOC /b /od 2^>NUL') do (
  rem set lastmod=%%a
  rem if "%lastmod%"=="" echo Could not locate files.&goto :eof
  copy /B "%%a" "%destDir%\"
)
pause

popd
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, Your code is copying only the .doc file. I have two source-directory and copy both file (new created file which is .doc and .txt) to a single directory. I edited my code (my first post) adding another source and destination.  Thank you.